# Android debugger - class file editor - source not found

Tags: android, debugging

In the Android debugger, when the source isn't available, it gets stuck there even when I try to step out (which works on a regular java project). Do I need to attach the source? If so, is it in the android sdk somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Nah you dont have to have the source attached.
It could be that the method you are calling is getting stuck (maybe you gave it funny inputs).

Usually when the debugger drops into code without the source i am able to continue clicking step next.

I would test out another method that is fairly simple to see if the method caused it.
Also make sure ADB is still running.